# Python OOP - how to organize situational code

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to organize a new Python project that is going to pull data and display it on different templates. The problem I'm running into is for each template, there are going to be different modifications/transformations needed on the data that feed into the template.

For example, my database may store information about trucks and I have 3 different templates. Before feeding data into the templates, I need to apply some custom logic to the data depending on the specific template.

For example, I may need to apply a unique ranking system to the data depending on the template and then take the top 5. Or maybe for some templates I also need to grab different associated data like tires.

Is there a design pattern or best-practice that would help me handle this? I could get by with an if switch like

`if template == "truck_tires": data = custom_truck_tires_logic(data)`

but I imagine there is a better way I'm unaware of.

Comment: You could have a list of functions associated with each template, maybe, and then run through the list in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class for every templates you can execute different logic based to object instance with isinstance.

```
class Template1:
   ...

class Template2:
   ...

my_template = Template1()
if isinstance(my_template, Template1):
   ...
elif isinstance(my_template, Template2):
   ...
```